# SmoothDivScroll jQuery Plugin not working if JS files are loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, asynchronous, smooth-scrolling

I'm using SmoothDivScroll and it was working great until I tried to load all the JS files asynchronously. I use my own async loading pattern using Ryan Grove's [Lazyload.js](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/blob/master/lazyload-min.js) but to be sure, I also tested with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)'s load/complete pattern and got the same result. I tested with a copy of the quick demo part from [SmoothDivScroll's homepage](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) and just added Modernizr. Without Modernizr, it was fine, but when I added Modernizr and its load/complete pattern to the head, and commented out all the JS before the end body tag, it wasn't working anymore. When you hover over the right arrow nothing happens, while hovering over the left causes the images to flicker. It should work the same either way. The Moderizr block should be equivalent to all the ones below it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        Modernizr.load([ {
            load: [
                '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js',
                '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js',
                '/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js',
                '/js/jquery.kinetic.js',
                '/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js'
            ],
            complete: 
                function () {     
                  $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
                            mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
                            manualContinuousScrolling: true,
                            autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        ]); 
    </script>        

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.kinetic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
                mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
                manualContinuousScrolling: true,
                autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified a code segment as below

```
      complete: 
            function () {     
                  $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
                        mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
                        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
                        autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
                  });
            }
        }
```

Attaching ready event handler to the document on complete of `Modernizr` won't work as the document is already loaded and parsed by the browser.

Comment: Thanks Ashwini that did the trick although I don't understand why exactly. Complete is fired on completion of what's loaded in load. And what's loaded may or may not finish before the DOM is ready. I'm not sure how to know if complete will finish before DOM ready in every situation in every browser.